# python replace backslash

Tags: python, regex, string, encoding

I'm trying to implement a simple helper class to interact with java-properties files. Fiddling with multiline properties I encountered a problem, that I can not get solved, maybe you can?

The unittest in the class first writes a multiline-property spanning over two lines to the property-file, then re-reads it and checks for equality. That just works. Now, if i use the class to add a third line to the property, it re-reads it with additional backslashes that I can't explain.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding=UTF-8 -*-

import codecs
import os, re
import fileinput
import unittest

class ConfigParser:
    reProp = re.compile(r'^(?P<key>[\.\w]+)=(?P<value>.*?)(?P<ext>[\\]?)$')
    rePropExt = re.compile(r'(?P<value>.*?)(?P<ext>[\\]?)$')
    files = []

    def __init__(self, pathes=[]):
       for path in pathes:
           if os.path.isfile(path):
               self.files.append(path)

    def getOptions(self):
        result = {}
        key = ''
        val = ''

        with fileinput.input(self.files, inplace=False) as fi:
            for line in fi:
                m = self.reProp.match(line.strip())
                if m:
                    key = m.group('key')
                    val = m.group('value')
                    result[key] = val
                else:
                    m = self.rePropExt.match(line.rstrip())
                    if m:
                        val = '\n'.join((val, m.group('value')))
                        result[key] = val

        fi.close()
        return result

    def setOptions(self, updates={}):
        options = self.getOptions()
        options.update(updates)

        with fileinput.input(self.files, inplace=True) as fi:
            for line in fi:
                m = self.reProp.match(line.strip())
                if m:
                    key = m.group('key')
                    nval = options[key]
                    nval = nval.replace('\n', '\\\n')
                    print('{}={}'.format(key,nval))

            fi.close()        

class test(unittest.TestCase):
    files = ['test.properties']
    props = {'test.m.a' : 'Johnson\nTanaka'}

    def setUp(self):
        for file in self.files:
            f = codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
            for key in self.props.keys():
                val = self.props[key]
                val = re.sub('\n', '\\\n', val)
                f.write(key + '=' + val)
            f.close()

    def teardown(self):
        pass

    def test_read(self):
        c = configparser(self.files) 
        for file in self.files:
            for key in self.props.keys():
                result = c.getOptions()
                self.assertEqual(result[key],self.props[key])

    def test_write(self):
        c = ConfigParser(self.files)
        changes = {}
        for key in self.props.keys():
            changes[key] = self.change_value(self.props[key])

        c.setOptions(changes)       
        result = c.getOptions()
        print('changes: ')
        print(changes)
        print('result: ')
        print(result)
        for key in changes.keys():
            self.assertEqual(result[key],changes[key],msg=key)

    def change_value(self, value):
        return 'Smith\nJohnson\nTanaka'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output of the testrun:

```
C:\pyt>propertyfileparser.py
changes:
{'test.m.a': 'Smith\nJohnson\nTanaka'}
result:
{'test.m.a': 'Smith\nJohnson\\\nTanaka'}
```

Any hints welcome...

Comment: Any particular reason you're avoiding the standard library's `ConfigParser`?

Comment: The ConfigParser reads INI files well, but not java-properties files. I thought about using RawConfigParser as base, but somehow it came differently.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding a backslash in front of new-lines when you are writing, you have to also remove them when you are reading. Uncommenting the line that substitutes '\n' with '\\n' solves the problem, but I expect this also means the file syntax is incorrect.

This happens only with the second line break, because you separate the value into an "oval" and an "nval" where the "oval" is the first line, and the "nval" the rest, and you only do the substitution on the nval.

It's also overkill to use regexp replacing to replace something that isn't a regexp. You can use val.replace('\n', '\\n') instead.

I'd do this parser very differently. Well, first of all, I wouldn't do it at all, I'd use an existing parser, but if I did, I'd read the file, line by line, while handling the line continuation issue, so that I had exactly one value per item in a list. Then I'd parse each item into a key and a value with a regexp, and stick that into a dictionary.

You instead parse each line separately and join continuation lines to the values after parsing, which IMO is completely backwards.

Comment: The value is not seperated into oval and nval, but the old value (oval) is not printed to the file, only the new value (nval) gets printed. nval contains "Smith\nJohnson\nTanaka" before replacement.

Comment: Even using str.replace does not solve the problem, I updated the code in the question.

Comment: @BeowulfOF: Your program is so strange I'm not gonna debug it without getting payed, but the string only containing "Johnson\nTanaka" is the result I got when I looked before, and it would also explain what happens. Apparently fileinput will redirect sys.stdout and it makes it very hard to debug. I'd stop using that if I was you.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to overlook my code. But when you do, do it right. No one is going to force you to do anything. There is really no point in engaging people, that use other methods than you. If you do not want to look through the code, don't do it, but to not try to force me, to code like you, thats rude.

Comment: @BeowulfOF: I'm not forcing you any more than you are forcing me. I'm giving you recommendations, it's up to you to listen. The essential issue has also been identified: You replace '\n' with '\\\n' when writing, but not when reading. Perhaps I misunderstood oval and nval, but it doesn't change the fact that you handle the first line as separately from the following lines, and these *are* the essential problems of the code.

Comment: look at my Regex, sure i handle the trailing backslash. I do explicitly not capture it as part of the value with the regex.

Comment: @BeowulfOF: Hint: `.*` is greedy. Yet another example of why not use complex things like regexps to do trivial things. Why not just line.strip()[-1] == '\\'? Much simpler.

Comment: Maybe simple, but not always correct. Maybe my way is not the best, maybe it is not your way, but if youre answering, you should help to get the answer for the actual problem of the question. I don't get that way of "i don't like your code, so solve your problem like me" it should be "your mistake is [], but it is complicated, so maybe you want another solution to your problem?"

Comment: @BeowulfOF: No, I should *help* you. Quite often the help you need most is somebody telling you that what you are doing is a bad idea. Seven hours after I've told you that we've now probably arrived at the answer you *wanted*: Your regexp is wrong, regexp doesn't work like you think it does. I could have rewritten it in a good way (and probably so could you) in an hour.

Comment: That regex wasn't even wrong, it was greedy, but since it was designed for the whole line, it was not even wrong, because it would only match, if the part with the backslash right before line end would match.

Comment: Anyway, we two won't get to a solution. So lets just give it a shot for the next time. You should never think you are even able to help the questioner, but be able to solve the problem. It could even be, that someone asks a question on how to make something without really needing it. Maybe someone just wants to try other ways than the simple obvious ones to just have it done? Why wouldn't you help him on this problem, but just on the (for you) only right way to do things.

Comment: @BeowulfOF: I can lead a horse to water, but not force it to drink. It will take me longer to debug your crummy code that to rewrite it a good way. So I'm not going to do what you want me too, because that would be a waste of time.